# Type issue when using data from php with Swift

Tags: php, swift, alamofire

I try to fill a table view with data downloaded from my database with Alamofire. I created a new NSObject class as followed :

```
class Repas: NSObject {
    var date: String
    var choix: String
    var note: Int

    init(date: String, choix: String, note: Int) {
        self.date = date
        self.choix = choix
        self.note = note
        super.init()
    }
}
```

The downloaded date respect this model format but when I try to insert them I got an error: `cannot assign a value of type 'String?' to a value of type '[Repas]'`.

I tried to force casting but it doesn't work. I don't understand how I can access my data with this method.

Comment: Possibly not related to your problem but: your init parameters name, game and rating are not being used but rather you are initialising your members to themselves. I am surprised this compiles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i found a solution. I change the php to get the response in JSON and then in swift I did:
` var miammiam: [Repas] = []` and I made a loop with the JSON response: 
` self.miammiam[i].date = repas_servi`